# Cannot set state inside componentDidMount

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps-api-3, fetch

I'm fetching some data from Google place search API and then fetching all the details of a particular place using its place ID. place search API returns an array of 20 records, First I loop through an array and get place_id of each place then again I fetch details of the place inside the loop and pushing it into an array then setting the state to that array. But when I do `{this.state.rows}` inside my render function, it gives me an empty array.
Here is my code Below:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
    Table,
    ProgressBar
} 
from 'react-bootstrap';

class Display extends Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state={
                rows: []
            }
        }


    componentDidMount(){
        var records = this.props.googleData;
        const API = this.props.api;
        const placeURI = this.props.placeURI;
        var rows = [];
        for (let p_id of records.results) {
            let dataURI = `${placeURI}${p_id.place_id}${API}`;
            let proxyUrl = 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/',
                targetUrl = dataURI
            fetch(proxyUrl + targetUrl)
            .then((res) => res.json())
            .then((data) => {
                let jsonData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
                //console.log(jsonData);
                rows.push(jsonData.result);
            })
            .catch((e) => console.log(`Error! ${e.message}`));
        }
        this.setState({
            rows:rows
        });
    };

    render() {
        console.log(this.state.rows); //this line is printing two arrays on console one is empty and the other is populated with values.
        return (
            <div>
                <ProgressBar now={45} />
                <Table striped bordered condensed hover responsive>
                  <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th>#</th>
                      <th>Name</th>
                      <th>Full Address</th>
                      <th>Phone Number</th>
                      <th>International P.no</th>
                      <th>Website</th>
                      <th>Rating</th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                    {this.state.rows.map(( listValue, index ) => {
                      return (
                        <tr key={index}>
                          <td>{listValue.name}</td>
                          <td>{listValue.formatted_address}</td>
                          <td>{listValue.name}</td>
                          <td>{listValue.name}</td>
                          <td>{listValue.name}</td>
                          <td>{listValue.name}</td>
                          <td>{listValue.name}</td>
                        </tr>
                      );
                    })}
                  </tbody>
                </Table>
                {this.state.rows+"hell"} // this line is not returning my current state
            </div>
        );
    }

}
export default Display;
```

Please consider the comments I added within code to know the behaviour. Please help me with this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fetch is asynchronous, so the results will get pushed to `rows` after the `setState` has executed, and nothing will update. To get the behavior you want, get rid of `var rows` and `this.setState({rows:rows})`, and replace `rows.push(jsonData.result)` with `this.setState(prevState => ({rows: [...prevState.rows, jsonData.result]}))`.

Keep in mind that the order of the rows will be determined by the order in which the fetch requests complete, so if you want to guarantee the order, you should create a list of `fetch` promises, and use a `Promise.all` to set the state. You could also use an async/await for loop, but this means each fetch will wait until the previous one has completed, removing parallelism and hurting performance.

UPDATE: In short, replace `componentDidMount` with this:

```
componentDidMount(){
    var records = this.props.googleData;
    const API = this.props.api;
    const placeURI = this.props.placeURI;

    for (let p_id of records.results) {
        const dataURI = `${placeURI}${p_id.place_id}${API}`;
        const proxyUrl = 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/',
            targetUrl = dataURI
        fetch(proxyUrl + targetUrl)
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((data) => {
            const jsonData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
            //console.log(jsonData);
            this.setState(prevState => ({rows: [...prevState.rows, jsonData.result]}))
        })
        .catch((e) => console.log(`Error! ${e.message}`));
    }
};
```

UPDATE 2: Here's some (untested) code with `Promise.all`, which preserves the row order:

```
componentDidMount(){
  const records = this.props.googleData;
  const API = this.props.api;
  const placeURI = this.props.placeURI;
  const proxyUrl = 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/'; // move this outside of component

  const rowFetches = records.results.map((p_id) =>
    fetch(`${proxyUrl}${placeURI}${p_id.place_id}${API}`)
    .then((res) => res.json())
  );
  const rows = Promise.all(rowFetches)
  .then((rows) => this.setState({rows}))
  .catch((e) => console.log(`Error! ${e.message}`));
}
```

Comment: could you please elaborate. I'm a beginner in React. Not getting your answer. It's far beyond my level

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm really really really grateful to you. I really appreciate. I wasted my 2 days in this. Thank you so much again

Answer (score 2):

It wont work because fetch is asynchronous. (e.g.: the line `rows.push(jsonData.result);` actually happens after you do `this.setState({rows: rows});` !)

I recommend you to create a new function just to create the array and set it in state. For better readability, you can use async/await syntax, here's how I'd do it:

```
async loadArray(results){
  const API = this.props.api;
  const placeURI = this.props.placeURI;
  let rows = [];
  for (let p_id of results) {
        let dataURI = `${placeURI}${p_id.place_id}${API}`;
        let proxyUrl = 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/',
            targetUrl = dataURI
        let res = await fetch(proxyUrl + targetUrl);
        res = await res.json();
        let jsonData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringfy(res))
        rows.push(jsonData.result)
    }
    this.setState({
        rows:rows
    });
}
componentDidMount(){
    const records = this.props.googleData;
    this.loadArray(records.results)
}
```

Comment: Async/await for loops are elegant, but they remove parallelism here, as each fetch will require a server response before the next one is sent.

Comment: You're correct. Did this way to keep only one setState. We can say I made the code work, but not the most optimised. Your answer is the ideal one

Comment: but I'm getting another error. `this.loadArray is not a function` inside `componentDidMount`